# bittrex php api wont read through all open orders

Tags: php

I am trying to write a bot to scan my open orders in bittrex using the php api.   If I have more then one open order this will only return the first one.  How do I get it to go through the rest of them?

```
// get open orders
$open_orders = $Adapter->get_open_orders( $market );

// loop through the open orders 
// this only goes to the first open order
// if there are more than one open order it doesn't iterate 
// through all of them.
foreach( $open_orders as $open_order_0 ) 
{
echo "inside foreach open_orders loop\n\n";
print_r( $open_order_0 );

}
```

Comment: Need more information, type and length of `$open_orders`, any errors, etc.

Comment: public function get_open_orders() {
    if( isset( $this->open_orders ) )
 return $this->open_orders;
 $open_orders = $this->exch->market_getopenorders();
 $this->open_orders = [];
 foreach( $open_orders['result'] as $open_order ) {
     $open_order['id'] = $open_order['OrderUuid'];
     $open_order['market'] = $open_order['Exchange'];

            unset( $open_order['Uuid'] );
     unset( $open_order['OrderUuid'] );
     unset( $open_order['Exchange'] );
  

     array_push( $this->open_orders, $open_order );
 }
  return $this->open_orders;
 }

Comment: I mean you need to check the type (`is_array($open_orders)`) and length (`count($open_orders)`), and if there is any errors during the foreach loop.

Comment: it is an array, but it only remembers the first length it is set to  example length of 3   then later is should go to 4  but it doesn't.  How do I clear or unset the multi dim array?